# PATH_INFO in vbscript ASP IIS

Tags: iis, asp-classic, vbscript, pathinfo

I was wondering if somebody could guide me to configure my web server to do the following:

http://mywebsite.com/default.asp/PATH

Where Path would be retreive into a var.

My problem is the following:

When I call : http://mywebsite.com/default.asp/PATH
I get a 404 error, probably because IIS thinks that default.asp is a directory?

Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to install URL Rewrite filter

Answer (score 1):

`default.asp` is a file. Files are always leaf objects in paths, so you can't have what you're asking for. What you can have is:

```
http://example.com/PATH/default.asp
```

or

```
http://example.com/default.asp?PATH
```

In the latter, `PATH` is a parameter passed to the ASP page `default.asp`.